# I am running a microbial predictive functional profiling script and having this strange error

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```
Tax4FunOutput <- Tax4Fun(QIIMESingleData, "SILVA123", fctProfiling = TRUE, 
            refProfile = "UProC", shortReadMode = TRUE, normCopyNo = TRUE)
```

> Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :    length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to
>   array extent

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable answer to help us answer your  question.  This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) has tips on how to do so.

Comment: Relevant things we do not (necessarily) know: from what package is `Tax2Fun`? How did you make `QIIMESingleData` (and what does it look like)?

Comment: Tax4Fun was used to predict microbes functions,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with your sample names. Please check your 16S OTU tables names and structure.

The following code runs OK:

```
library(Tax4Fun)
QIIMESingleData <- importQIIMEData("http://tax4fun.gobics.de/QIIME/HMP_0.97_table.txt")
Tax4FunOutput <- Tax4Fun(QIIMESingleData, "SILVA123", fctProfiling = TRUE, 
                         refProfile = "UProC", shortReadMode = TRUE, normCopyNo = TRUE)
```

This one gives an error:

```
## DO NOT RUN 
QIIMESingleData2 <- QIIMESingleData
QIIMESingleData2$sampleNames <- "a"
Tax4FunOutput <- Tax4Fun(QIIMESingleData2, "SILVA123", fctProfiling = TRUE, 
                         refProfile = "UProC", shortReadMode = TRUE, normCopyNo = TRUE)
## END DO NOT RUN
## Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
## length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```